# sh syntax to handle zero files matching a wildcard, as well as more?

Tags: macos, command-line, shell, bash-scripting, sh

I want to write a `/bin/sh` shell script which will handle any files matching a wildcard. It's easy to handle 1 or more matching files. However, I'm finding it awkward to handle the case of 0 matching files.

The obvious construct is:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *.ext; do
  handle "$f"
done
```

where `*.ext` could be one or more expressions which the shell compares to file paths, and `handle` is a shell command which runs correctly if given a path to an existing file, but fails if giving a path which does not map to a file. (In the case that provokes this question, they are `*.flac` and `ffmpeg`, but I think that doesn't matter.)

If there are matching files `foo.ext`, `bar.ext`, then this script performs

```
handle "foo.ext"
handle "bar.ext"
```

as expected. However, if there *not* any matching files, this script gives an error message like,

```
handle: *.ext: No such file or directory
```

I think I understand why this happens: the [*bash* man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh) (which I assume is valid for `/bin/sh` also) says the "list of words following `in` is expanded, generating a list of items.… If the expansion of the items following in results in an empty list, no commands are executed, and the return status is 0." Apparently when `*.ext` "is expanded", the list of results includes `*.ext`, instead of an empty list. But that doesn't explain how to stop it happening.

(Update: There is a [`sh (1)` man page from the Heirloom Project](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh/sh.1.html) which describes the Bourne Shell `sh`, not the later Bourne Again Shell `bash`. Under [*File Name Generation*](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh/sh.1.html#7), it clearly says, "If no file name is found that matches the pattern then the word is left unchanged." It explains why `sh` leaves a `*.ext` pattern in the list.)

What is a compact, idiomatic way to write this loop so that it will run zero times with no errors if there are no matching files, but will run once for each matching file? Better yet, what will work with multiple patterns like:

```
for f in *.ext1 special.ext1 *.ext2; do ...
```

I prefer to use syntax compatible with `/bin/sh`, for portability. I happen to be using Mac OS X 10.11.6, but I'm hoping for syntax which works on any Unix-like OS.

I came up with a couple of clumsy, non-idiomatic ways to write such a loop. If I don't immediately get good answers, I'll contribute those as answers, for the record.

Comment: This is trivial to handle if you're willing to move up to bash.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I prefer to stick to `/bin/sh`, but it's not absolute. I think an answer of the form "switch to bash, then do this" is helpful. It won't be as good as one which says, "here's how to do it in sh", but maybe such an answer doesn't exist.

Comment: bash has `nullglob`, which will prevent the loop from even running.

Comment: Great! Turn that into a good answer, and you'll get points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest portable way to do this is to skip the loop for if the expansion doesn't produce something that actually exists:

```
for f in *.ext1 *.ext2; do
  [ -e "$f" ] || continue
  handle "$f"
done
```

Explanation: suppose there are several .ext2 files, but no .ext1 files. In that case the wildcards will expand to `*.ext1` `filea.ext2` `fileb.ext2` `filec.ext2`. So `[ -e "*.ext1" ]` fails and it runs `continue`, which skips the rest of that iteration of the loop. Then `[ -e "filea.ext2" ]` etc succeed, and those iterations of the loop run normally.

BTW, you can modify this to e.g. `[ -f "$f" ] || continue` to skip anything that isn't a plain file (if you want to skip directories etc).

Of course, if you're running under bash, you can just run `shopt -s nullglob` first so it doesn't leave unmatched patterns in the list. And then `shopt -u nullglob` afterward to prevent unexpected side effects (e.g. `grep pattern *.nonexistent` will try to read from stdin if `nullglob` is set).

Comment: Clever use of `continue`, and excellent explanation.  I think the use of `nullglob` turns into a second answer, if I understand it correctly. @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrahams mentioned it in a comment under the question.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to the Bourne Again Shell (`/bin/bash`) from the Bourne Shell (`/bin/sh`), and a simple solution becomes possible.

The [`bash(1)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) mentions the **nullglob** option:

> If set, bash allows patterns which match no files (see **Pathname Expansion** above) to expand to a null string, rather than themselves.

The **Pathname Expansion** section says:

> After word splitting, …bash scans each word for the characters *****, **?**, and **[**. If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of file names matching the pattern. If no matching file names are found, and the shell option **nullglob** is not enabled, the word is left unchanged. If the **nullglob** option is set, and no matches are found, the word is removed.…

So, setting the **nullglob** option gives the desired behaviour for patterns. If no file matches the pattern, the loop does not execute.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.ext; do
  handle "$f"
done
```

But the **nullglob** option may well interfere with desired behaviour for other commands. So, you will probably find it wise to save the existing setting of **nullglob**, and restore it afterwards. Fortunately, the `shopt -p` builtin command emits output in a form that may be reused as input. But it emits output for all options, so use `grep` to pick out the **nullobj** setting. See the log below (where `$` indicates the bash command prompt):

```
$ shopt -p | grep nullglob
shopt -u nullglob
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ shopt -p | grep nullglob
shopt -s nullglob
```

So, the final bash syntax to handle zero or more file matching a wildcard pattern looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVED_NULLGLOB=$(shopt -p | grep nullglob)
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.ext; do
  handle "$f"
done
eval "$SAVED_NULLGLOB"
```

Also, the question mentioned multiple patterns, like:

```
for f in *.ext1 special.ext1 *.ext2; do ...
```

The **nullglob** option doesn't affect a word in the list which is not a "pattern", so `special.ext1` will still get passed to the loop. The only solution for this is [@Gordon Davisson](https://superuser.com/users/7778/gordon-davisson)'s `continue` expression, `[ -e "$f" ] || continue` .

Acknowledgement: both [@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://superuser.com/users/26316/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) and [@Gordon Davisson](https://superuser.com/users/7778/gordon-davisson) alluded to `bash(1)` and its **nullglob** option. Thank you. Since they didn't immediately contribute a answer with a fully-worked example, I am doing so myself.